# Filtering data validation dropdown list based on cells containing specific test

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel column that I would like to use as a base for 4 separate dropdown lists.

StudyName_SlideName_PD1_1stRun_NoFabBlock_1/250_Rabbit_pH6
StudyName_SlideName_PD1_1stRun_NoFabBlock_1/100_Rabbit_pH6
StudyName_SlideName_PD1_1stRun_NoFabBlock_1/150_Rabbit_pH9
StudyName_SlideName_FOXP3_1stRun_NoFabBlock_1/150_Mouse_pH6

I would like to create 4 different dropdown lists which will find the cells containing the values below separately and show me the options in the dropdown menus.

```
Rabbit_pH6

Rabbit_pH9

Mouse_pH6

Mouse_pH9
```

For example: Rabbit_pH6 dropdown list would show me the options below in the dropdown list
StudyName_SlideName_PD1_1stRun_NoFabBlock_1/250_Rabbit_pH6
StudyName_SlideName_PD1_1stRun_NoFabBlock_1/100_Rabbit_pH6

Please help me to find a solution for this problem,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This formula creates a list based on the chosen value in the data validation pulldown menu: **ARRAY FOMULA:  STRG + SHIFT + ENTER**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$4,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND($L$1,$A$1:$A$4)),ROW($A$1:$A$4)),ROW(A1))),"")
```

Pull the formula down. `A1:A4` are the cells you want to search. `L1` is the cell where you can put the data validation pulldown menu. Change these according to your needs. You can feed this list to another data validation pulldown menu.